# Determining all possible integer output for a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given a function: $y = f(a) \cdot x + g(a)$, where $x$ and $a$ are limited to the integers. Is there a way to determine the set of all integers that $y$ can be?

For further context, $f(a)$ is linear and $g(a)$ is quadratic, and for all integer $a$'s, $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are integers.

In a comment, I asked a new question. This is that question.
Here is a separate, but related question. Is it possible to show that there is a greatest integer that is not contained in the set of all y's

Comment: Can you say more about what values $f$ and $g$ can assume? That's crucial. For integer inputs, are they integers? Rationals? Irrationals?

Comment: For integer inputs, they are always integers.

Answer (score 0):

You have no numerical values so you could write {${y|y = f(a)*x + g(a), a, x \epsilon \mathbb{Z}}$}

That's my geuss

Comment: I mean in a less general since.

Comment: You can't get anymore specific really

Comment: Here is a separate, but related question. Is it possible to show that there is a greatest integer that is not contained in the set of all $y$'s?

Comment: If we know what the functions $f$ and $g$ are then yes.

Comment: I'm not asking for you to do it, I am asking in a general sense. How would one go about showing that/showing that there is no greatest integer?

Comment: Ross's awnser is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Without more about $f$ and $g$ you can't say much.  For your new question, no.  For example, $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ might always be even.  Then $y$ can never be odd, so there is no greatest integer not representable this way.

Comment: How would one go about proving that in a general sense?

Comment: On the other hand, if $f(a)$ ever is $1$ or $-1$, then all integers are representable.  There just isn't enough information to decide.